# Can I export constants created with enum::fields in perl?

Tags: perl, constants, exporter

Can I export constants created with `enum::fields`?  For example:

```
package XLine {
    use enum::fields qw{VAL SLOPE INTERVAL};
    use parent qw(Exporter);

    our @EXPORT = qw(VAL SLOPE INTERVAL);

    sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = bless [], $class;
    return($self);
    }
}

my $x = XLine->new();

printf("INTERVAL = %d\n", INTERVAL);
```

Is there a different "constant" package I should use instead?  I used this one because I read that it was fast, here: http://neilb.org/reviews/constants.html

Comment: By the document you quote, one of the points of the module is so that one can subclass it.  However, the shown code mixes things from classes and (non-class) packages (you don't "export" things from a class, but rather provide _class_ data/methods) so I am not sure i get what you need.

Comment: I understand your comment.  That's exactly what I'm trying to do is export a constant from a class.  This is not normally the way I would use a class, and in fact everything else is a method.  In this case I'm getting double duty from the package: once as a class, and once as a regular package.

Comment: OK. So, the `VAL` (etc) are meant to be names for index values, so one can do `$self->[VAL]` instead of using `0`.  As such, do you really want to provide them to the outside world ... ?  If you only want to "export" some variables (define them in a class and made them available outside), I'd recommend `Readonly` and/or `Const::Fast`.

Comment: I see what you mean about having a separate package for the constants.  The choice of how (not where) to do the constants was based on the article I mentioned.  The `enum::fields` is supposed to be faster than either `Readonly` or `Const::Fast`.  I haven't tested it.

Comment: "_export a constant from a class_" -- this can be done by simply defining a class (global) variable, like `const our $VAR => 5;`  and class user can use it as `$ClassName::VAR`.  (I used `Const::Fast`.) No need to actually export.  But if you actually need values for `VAL` (etc) deinfed by `enum::fields` then it seems that you indeed may need to Export them.

Comment: "_faster than_"  -- from what I know the main indea of `enum::fields` is very specific: to have nice names for indices in a class that uses arrays for its data.  If that's what you need it for then there is no debate, that's what you need.  But as for speed, in my benchmarks `Const::Fast` is practically _equal_ to reading off values for normal variables (for all of scalars, arrays, hashes); how does one get faster than that? The `Readonly` is the same for scalars, but drops (a lot) for arrays/hashes.

Comment: Actually, I was looking for benchmarks for `Const::Fast` when I found that article.  For this project, I was using a bunch of fixed (const) hash keys that were quite lengthy, and they are used millions of times.  On a different project, I'd probably lean toward something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

enum::fields is not the problem here. The code works when you add [`XLine->import(qw(INTERVAL));`](http://p3rl.org/import) or, more realistically/following best practices, move the XLine package into its own .pm file.

Comment: Dangit.  I was just testing the `.pm` module by just adding code to the bottom and running it directly.  `./XLine.pm`  Thanks!